# The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Почему выпрыгивает исключение в методе Load? Если сделать его синхронным все работает нормально.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
        {
            private readonly List<string> _listImageUri;
            private int _currentIndex;
            private ImageSource _currentImage;
            public ObservableCollection<Image> CustomControls { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Image>();
            public MainViewModel()
            {
                _listImageUri = new List<string>();
                Load("путь к папке");
            }

            private async void Load(string s)
            {
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    foreach (var fileInfo in new DirectoryInfo(s).GetFiles())
                    {
                        _listImageUri.Add(fileInfo.FullName);
                        Image img = new Image();// здесь выпрыгивает exception
                        img.Height = 100;
                        img.Margin = new Thickness(5);
                        img.Width = 100;
                        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
                        bmp.BeginInit();
                        bmp.UriSource = new Uri(fileInfo.FullName);
                        bmp.DecodePixelWidth = 100;
                        bmp.EndInit();
                        img.Source = bmp;
                        CustomControls.Add(img);
                        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CustomControls));
                    }
                });
            }
}
```

**Exception**

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что вы создаёте картинку (`new Image`) не в UI-потоке.

Делайте не так. Получайте список файлов через async-функцию, а создание UI-элементов делайте в UI-потоке.

```
BitmapImage GetFrozenImage(string path)
{
    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
    bmp.BeginInit();
    bmp.UriSource = new Uri(path);
    bmp.DecodePixelWidth = 100;
    bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bmp.EndInit();
    bmp.Freeze();
    return bmp;
}

class ImageAndPath
{
    public string Path;
    public BitmapImage Image;
}

IEnumerable<ImageAndPath> LoadImages(string directory)
{
    return 
        new DirectoryInfo(s).GetFiles()
                            .Select(f => new ImageAndPath()
                                    {
                                        Image = GetFrozenImage(f.FullName)),
                                        Path = f.FullName
                                    };
}

private async void Load(string s)
{
    var images = await Task.Run(() => LoadImages(s).ToList());
    foreach (var imageAndPath in images)
    {
        _listImageUri.Add(imageAndPath.Path);
        // а вот это вообще не должно быть в VM!
        // зачем вы создаёте UI-элемент тут??
        Image img = new Image()
        {
            Height = 100,
            img.Width = 100,
            Margin = new Thickness(5),
            Source = imageAndPath.Image
        };

        CustomControls.Add(img);
    }
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CustomControls));
}
```

---

С точки зрения MVVM, создавать контролы в VM неверно. Лучше сделать так:

1. В VM положить `ObservableCollection` каких-нибудь объектов, включающих битмапы.
2. В UI положить какой-нибудь там `ItemsControl`, в котором `ItemsSource` привязать к `ObservableCollection`, а в `ItemTemplate` положить `<Image Source="{Binding ЗдесьИмяСвойстваГдеЛежитБитмап}"/>`.

Comment: но получение списка файлов и так достаточно быстро выполняется, в то время как image может создаваться очень большое количество, что существенно тормозит основной поток. Вся идея была в том чтобы вынести создание картинок в отдельный поток.

Comment: @Lightness: Дописал код. Это создание битмапов медленное. Чтение файловой системы тоже медленное, если у юзера «уснул» винт, программа не должна тормозить, выглядеть будет очень непрофессионально. А вот создание контролов быстрое.

Comment: @Lightness: Подправил код, дописал `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`.

Comment: я понимаю что контролы не нужно создавать в VM, но другое решение не смог придумать. Когда пользователь выбирает путь к папке с картинками, наполняется  ObservalCollection которая привязана к ListView, в котором картинки и отображаются.

Comment: @Lightness: Дописал ответ снова.

Comment: VladD, огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Lightness: Пожалуйста!